# Encryption unsuccessful

Tags: applications

I am a senior citizen with very limited tech knowledge.  I woke up this AM with the encryption unsuccessful error notice on my Android.  I have been searching all these sites for help and cannot understand the "lingo". (bootloop, twrp, etc.)  Can someone tell me EXACTLY what to do?  Should I just push the "reset phone" button?  What will happen then?  Will I really lose everything?  By "losing everything" what does that mean?  Can I still make phone calls, see my pictures, play games?

Comment: You should edit your question and provide more details: What phone or tablet model are you talking about? Do you know which Android version is running on your device? Have you set a PIN/password and is the device encrypted? A screen-shot may be taken by a second cam or phone would also be good to have.

Comment: @Robert i don't think this matters. from this point there is no return. If this message appears you already lost everything

Comment: @alecxs That is not true. I had a similar message on my old encrypted Moto G after every OS update. Just another reboot and everything was fine again. In my case it seems to be a timing problem that only occurred after an update. Therefore I would never directly erase the phone.

Comment: do you mean decryption unsuccessful or encryption unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an attempt to Encrypt the Data partition failing.

Usually it fails from corrupt storage, and also from power loss.. did you unplug it while the encryption was in progress ?

The Wipe Everything option refers to everything that is specifically stored on the devices internal storage and data partition.

The SIM Card contacts will not be removed, however the device's locally stored contacts will be deleted.

The Files, ( photo's, documents etc.. ) that are stored on the External SD Card, will also Not be wiped, however any photo's taken and stored to the infernal storage will be wiped in the process.

No you will NOT lose access to features like calling, it will only remove the personal files you have created.

It should say "Factory Reset" to clarify what happens, but the warning is very basic and designed just to show you a problem occurred while encrypting.